# setInterval does not stop after second call

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am currently working on a battle system.
The health gets calculated every 200ms, and I'm using a Interval. It works pretty good, until I start the game - the Interval again. It doesn't stop anymore.

It is a lot of code - I have also an online live demo here http://wernersbacher.de/pro/coinerdev/

Like I said - works the first, but not the second.

So, just the main code:

```
var frameStop;
 // Draws Startscreen
    function showStartRaid(name) {               
            playerBTC = btc;
            playerBTCs = btcs;
            playerName = nick;

            // Sets stats for called level
            enemyBTC = dun[name]["buyer"]["btc"];
            enemyBTCs = dun[name]["buyer"]["btcs"];
            enemyName = dun[name]["buyer"]["label"];   
            enemyNum = dun[name]["meta"]["base"];         

            /* Reset everything in html */
    }

    var battle = false;

    $(".raid_building").click(function() {           
        //Draws level
        showStartRaid(name);

        //Sets start BTC as fighting stats (they will decrease during battle)
        fplayerBTC = playerBTC;
        fenemyBTC = enemyBTC;
        //Click on "Start"
        $("#startRaid").click(function() {
            function raiden() {
                //Calculates fighting
                fenemyBTC -= playerBTCs/frameMinus;
                fplayerBTC -= enemyBTCs/frameMinus;

                /*Draws stats and health here in html */

                if(fplayerBTC >= 0 && fenemyBTC >= 0)
                    console.log("battle goes on")
                else {
                    //If battle is over, stop it
                    clearInterval(frameStop);
                }
            }
            //Start battle
            frameStop = setInterval(raiden, frameRaid);
        });
    });
```

Thanks for any help, I'm helpless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your code, *every time* `.raid_building` is clicked, you hook up a *new* handler for clicks on `#startRaid`. So that means, if `.raid_building` is clicked twice, you'll have **two** handlers for clicks on `#startRaid`, both of which start a new interval timer. Your `frameStop` variable will only contain the handle of one of them; the other will continue. And of course, a third click will compound the problem (you'll have three `click` handlers, each of which fires up a new interval timer). And so on...

Move the code hooking `click` on `#startRaid` **outside** the click handler on `.raid_building`.

Comment: I would also add that you could leave it inside but do an `.off('click').on('click'`, though I would not recommend it.

Comment: @AdamMerrifield: Indeed, good point. Sometimes that's what you want. Probably not here, but still...